# How do I write a compiler in C?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ctags

I want to write a compiler in C.

Whats basics do I have to learn for creating a compiler?

Comment: Assuming this is a serious question, a compiler for what language, and for what purpose (self-development, assignment, part of a product)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler

Answer (score 2):

Start by reading [the dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily recommend that as the first book to look at. Although you'd want to read it eventually

Answer (score 0):

flex and yacc may help

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: This is a good suggestion. :)